# How to solve the out of memory issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, memory

I'm having this issue below.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 301465600) (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/romanzzino/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue related to the memory limit on your server or installation.

Improve these values on your `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` file, they're on your root installation folder and in your pub folder.

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 38000
```

If the solution above doesn't resolve, try to change the same limits on your `php.ini` file on your server.

Comment: I already did those steps and it still does not work. Do you have any other solution.

The problem is that you only sign up for the Magento admin in the orders section when clicking on orders.

All Magento works correctly.

Comment: Url: 
 https://Magento.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/fdccec77213d55ef70e4b0d72c38940c/

Comment: Try to disable some third-party extension that has relation with the order.

Comment: Excuse my English!!!

Comment: I already do it and it does not work.

Comment: Too low memory limit will throw a fatal "Allowed memory size" NOT "Out of memory"!

Answer (score 0):

The memory is limited by the `.htaccess` and the `.user.ini` files used by Magento 2.

Increase the memory limit (e.g. up to 2048M) in the following places:

1..user.ini

```
memory_limit = 768M
```

2..htaccess (2 places)

```
php_value memory_limit 768M
```

3.pub/.user.ini

```
memory_limit = 768M
```

4.pub/.htaccess (2 places)

```
php_value memory_limit 768M
```

Quoted from Dmitry Fedyuk https://mage2.pro/t/topic/3868/4